# Best way to reverse the order of list items

Tags: php, html

I have an exported Skype history that's been converted to HTML.

I have 20,000 list items < li > with varying amounts of html between each.

Only thing is it's in reverse order, what's the best way to swap it round - ie make the first < li > and all it's content the last one and the last one the first one?

A php solution? or is there a simpler way with specific software. The CSS solution isn't ideal.

If this would be the input as html

```
<li>stuff in here</li>
<li><div>MORE stuff in here</div></li>
<li><span class = "test">yet even more stuff in here</span></li>
```

this would be the output in html - saved as a file

```
<li><span class = "test">yet even more stuff in here</span></li>
<li><div>MORE stuff in here</div></li>
<li>stuff in here</li>
```

only there' 20,000 of them

Comment: Please add a sample input and expected output. whether it is text string?

Comment: Yes but putting 20,000 list items into an array? I'm not sure how that's possible or if it is possible.

Comment: Why do you think that the CSS solution isn't ideal ? If you're not using AJAX to get the list of 20,000 record in part by part then CSS perfectly worked here as `@Mehedi Hasan Siam` answered.

Comment: Is this really a php question?

Comment: I should have said the CSS solution is not workable. The output absolutely needs to be in order, no changed by CSS as it is going into an ebook.

Comment: I would have thought yes it's a PHP question as it's so often the best way to take large amounts of html and alter it in some way. At least I've found that in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Split the Lists into an array
- Reverse the order
- Output the reversed list

```
$input = <<<_HTML
<li>stuff in here</li>
<li><div>MORE stuff in here</div></li>
<li><span class ="test">yet even more stuff in here</span></li>
_HTML;

$list = [];
preg_match_all('~<li>(.*?)</li>~', $input, $list);
$list = array_reverse($list[0]);

foreach($list as $item)
    echo $item, PHP_EOL;
```

Results in

```
<li><span class ="test">yet even more stuff in here</span></li>
<li><div>MORE stuff in here</div></li>
<li>stuff in here</li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, a very elegant solution that did a lot of heavy lifting! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can go to HTML to get your desired target

You must have an order list type. If it is `<ul>` you can go for this

```css
ul {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul > li {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>stuff in here</li>
  <li><div>MORE stuff in here</div></li>
  <li><span class = "test">yet even more stuff in here</span></li>
</ul>
```

if you have `<ol>` you can go for this

```css
ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>stuff in here</li>
  <li><div>MORE stuff in here</div></li>
  <li><span class = "test">yet even more stuff in here</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That is such a cool idea I wouldn't have come up by myself. You can do this with flex also via `{ display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse; }`.

Comment: It's going to be made into an ebook, not seen through a browser -  I need the code to be as it is, not manipulated by CSS, that's why it's not ideal

Comment: By the way this is the best way to show items in reverse order (I will use this trick in my projects).

Comment: @Tomate boss if you have HTML which means it can be integrated by CSS. You can also go for PHP but you must modify the code, otherwise there is no option

Comment: Sorry Mehedi you don't seem to understand my original question. I have a huge amount of HTML which need to be reversed and presented as html so it can be imported into other uses NOT manipulated after the fact.

Comment: So you have HTML code and that HTML code will be converted to pdf or ebook right?

Comment: @Tomate what's the problem with `Markus Zeller` answer

Comment: Nothing Markus' answer is perfect.

Comment: you're `ordered list` is broken though. It's no longer numbered.